# Angular site not loading from oldest IE11 on Win7 on a Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2012-r2

I've deployed 2 asp.net mvc websites to windows server 2012 R2, on two different websites (in IIS). One runs on port 81 and the other on 91.

One is plain asp.net mvc and works correct from all machines (at least, all I've tried).

The other one also is asp.net mvc but loads an Angular module. This also works, from my development machine (Win10), but not from windows 7 and IE11.
This is run on a virtual machine from microsoft, and also has the not automatically updated version of I11 (from 2 years ago) just like the client has.

And there is nothing to see on the browser, because I get a timeout. So every request on the win10 (and computers of 8 collegue's) machine go ok, but on win7 + old IE11 I get a timeout.

Any hint in which direction to look?

From the win7 / ie11 combination I CAN reach another website I published to Azure as Azure website, and that site is similair built.

Comment: Can you ping the host the app is on? What does your browser dev tools show? Fiddler?

Comment: Fiddler show nothing because I get a timeout. I can not ping the server but I can't either from the pc's I CAN reach the site from, so I think that is a server setting, not to allow pings?

Comment: I think the fact that this is an Angular app is irrelivant TBH. The server doesnt' (shouldn't) care what client side JS frameworks are used. 
Can you request a static image off the file system OK?

Comment: @LdJ: good question, they can't reach that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we have figured it out.
The client was using IE11 in compatibility mode. 
I'm not sure what that means, besides that it behaves like an 'older / earlier' version of IE.
But I don't know to what version *exactly*.

What I did know, was that it was causing the defects.

The solution:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

as first element under de `<head>` declaration.